# Converting double to String, getting error saying I can't convert String to double

Tags: java, string, double

I think I might be going insane. I wrote a simple method, taking a double, converting to string, taking out the decimal and reversing the order of the numbers. Every time I run it, I get an error saying that I can't change a String to a double, which is true, but also the complete opposite of what I'm doing.
I've tried double += ""; and double = Double.toString(double);, and I get the same error. The complete method:

```
   public static String favNumber(double bank) {
      bank = Double.toString(bank);
      bank = bank.replace('.',"");
      String ret = "";
      int end = bank.length() - 1;
      for(int i = end; i >= 0; i--) {
         char add = bank.charAt(i);
         ret += add;
      }
      return ret;
   }
```

Additional stuff: I swear the identifier names make sense in the grand scheme of my code (for a school assignment), and I am not allowed to use StringBuilder, hence the for loop.

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the variable `bank` has type `double` - you've declared it thus in the first set of parentheses.

Then on the second line, you take an expression of type `String` - namely `Double.toString(bank)`, and try to assign it to the variable `bank`.  That is, you're trying to assign a value of type `String` to a variable of type `double` - and that's what the compiler is preventing you from doing.

Answer (score 3):

`bank` is of type `double`. Then you cannot assign a `String` value to it. Do this:

```
String bankStr = Double.toString(bank);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have attempted to assign the `String` returned by `Double.toString` back to 
`bank` which was the original `double` variable. Here I have used two different variables, one a `double` and one a `String`...

```
public static String favNumber(double thedouble) {
  String bank = Double.toString(thedouble);
  bank = bank.replace('.',"");
  String ret = "";
  int end = bank.length() - 1;
  for(int i = end; i >= 0; i--) {
     char add = bank.charAt(i);
     ret += add;
  }
  return ret;
}
```